# C# property value doesn't get modified within Javascript/ jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I initialize a property within the Controller's Constructor.

```
public BookController()
{
  SessionProvider.SessionLoadSceanrio = false;
}
```

I have an Action Method which reset the property again on a button click event.

```
public ActionResult LoadScenario(int bookId)
{
  SessionProvider.SessionLoadSceanrio = true;
  // remaining code
  return Json(ScenarioId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Following javascript code is in my view which is called when the button is clicked.

```
var BookHandler = {
  $("#btnLoadScen").click(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("LoadScenario", "Book")",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            'bookId': BookHandler.getBookId()
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            var scenarioId = response;
                            var isLoadScenario = "@Portal.Presentation.Web.Planning.MVC.App_Start.SessionProvider.SessionLoadSceanrio";
                            //otherproperties
                            window.open("@Url.Action("Index", "BookScenario", new {loadScenario = "_loadScenario"}).replace('_loadScenario', isLoadScenario), tabId);

                        },
                        error: function () {
                        }
                    });

                });
}
```

My problem is when I click the button, value of property  changes in the Controller. But it doesn't change in my javascript code.Please see the screen capture of the developer tool.
[image: ScreenCapture]

does Anyone has a clue on this?

Comment: I see there's one error in console. What does it say?

Comment: The code which you have pasted is different from screenshot. Are you sure you are referring to the same code while running it?

Comment: thushar .. it's css error.. we can ignore it..

Comment: Mike its the same code. The developer tool shows with value. that's what I think it appears different.And I didn't list here some properties to increase readability. But it's actually there in the code

Comment: You must reload your page to change it.

Comment: Reloading the page. I did that. But same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the razor syntax. then initially page loaded , values are set, and these values are string , not a variable anymore. then  you can't get session value updated again.

please get session value from an AJAX call and set to your variable.

Answer (score 3):

The code below will only be evaluated once you get the view from server and will not be re-evaluated after your ajax call.

```
var isLoadScenario = "@Portal.Presentation.Web.Planning.MVC.App_Start.SessionProvider.SessionLoadSceanrio";
```

In order to do what you intended, you will need to return SessionLoadSceanrio in your response.

You can do it like:

```
    public ActionResult LoadScenario(int bookId)
    {
      SessionProvider.SessionLoadSceanrio = true;
      // remaining code
      return Json(new {ScenarioId, SessionLoadSceanrio = SessionProvider.SessionLoadSceanrio}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```